# Mosaic images with Matlab

Tags: matlab, mosaic

I have a question about how can I do something. I have a folder with different images (each image has 3 bands). For example.

```
Img_244_234_1_1.tif
Img_244_234_1_2.tif

Img_250_234_1_1.tif
Img_250_234_1_2.tif
```

What I need to do is to mosaic the images by name (for example, all the number 244, 250...). Now, I'm doing it manually in that way:

```
image1 = imread('C:\Prueba\Img_244_234_1_1.tif','tif');
image2 = imread('C:\Prueba\Img_244_234_1_2.tif','tif');
image3 = imread('C:\Prueba\Img_250_234_1_1.tif','tif');
image4 = imread('C:\Prueba\Img_250_234_1_2.tif','tif');

image_result1 = cat(2,image1,image2);
image_result1 = cat(2,image1,image2);
```

How can I automatize using the date number (244,250...) which always it's in the same output name position?

Really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loops (like `for x=[244,255]`) and the concatenation of strings: `['C:\Prueba\Img_' x '_234_1_1.tif']` will evaluate to `'C:\Prueba\Img_244_234_1_1.tif' if x was 244.

Answer (score 0):

If your file name is well organized, then the following code should work.

```
cd('C:\Prueba\');
files = dir('*.tif');
for i=1:2:numel(files)
    image1 = imread(files(i).name);
    image2 = imread(files(i+1).name);
    image_result = cat(2,image1,image2);
end
```